# With CTE recursion how to traverse a arrays of arrays and return aggregate product with Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I have a JSONB rolumns named rules. Here is a data example:

```
{
    "RuleProperties": null,
    "Rules": [
        {
            "RuleProperties": {
                "field": "pnt_name",
                "label": "pnt_name",
                "operator": "contains",
                "type": "string",
                "Value": "^"
            },
            "Rules": [
                {
                    "RuleProperties": {
                        "field": "pnt_name",
                        "label": "pnt_name",
                        "operator": "contains",
                        "type": "string",
                        "Value": "P"
                    },
                    "Rules": [
                        {
                            "RuleProperties": {
                                "field": "pnt_name",
                                "label": "pnt_name",
                                "operator": "contains",
                                "type": "string",
                                "Value": "SK"
                            },
                            "Rules": null,
                            "XOR": "and"
                        }
                    ],
                    "XOR": "and"
                }
            ],
            "XOR": "and"
        },
        {
            "RuleProperties": {
                "field": "pnt_name",
                "label": "pnt_name",
                "operator": "contains",
                "type": "string",
                "Value": "R"
            },
            "Rules": null,
            "XOR": "and"
        }
    ],
    "XOR": "and"
}
```

It concists of rules with rules n-depth. How to use CTE and resursively build an aggregate of RulesProperties>Value.
So take each value in RulesProperties and concatenate it with the prior arrays RuleProperty>Value? The product could be ^PSK and ^R.

The depth of the array is unknown

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is easier achieved with a recursive function than with a CTE

Comment: "*The product could be ^PSK and ^R*" - I don't get it. I could understand `^PSKR`, or `["^PSK", "R"]`, but why `^R`? What exactly do you want to concatenate with what?

Comment: @Bergi the latter with a little correction  ["^PSK", "^R"]

Comment: Yeah that's what I can't understand how it's built. Why does `^`  become part of `^R`? What would happen if there were other rules next to the `P` value?

Comment: It would help if you could add the algorithm as pseudocode (or Python or JS or something)

Comment: I meant as an imperative (or functional) recursive algorithm, in a normal programming language, not SQL. Without "somehow" - if you cannot define how to compute the result in general, we cannot answer how to do it in SQL specifically. Please [edit] your question.

Comment: OK, I will give a shot